# Psycopg `connection.notices` contains notices belonging to previous queries rather than latest query

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using Python 2.7.3 and Psycopg 2.5.4 in a virtualenv to connect to PostgreSQL 9.1.13 on Debian 7.6 amd64.

`notices` property of the connection object I create is always one or more queries behind in the PostgreSQL notifications that it is supposed to contain. After each query that I execute (`cursor.execute()`, `conn.commit()` and `cursor.close()`), I run:

```
while conn.notices:
    print(conn.notices.pop(0))
```

But the notices always seem to be related to previous queries. I'm not sure if I have a bug in my program or Psycopg fetches notices lazily. Sometimes lots of notices get printed after a single query and they are all related to a number of previous queries which raises the suspicion that notices are being bulk fetched from the server by psycopg at a random time.

I have used libpqxx C++ library to connect to the same DB, and the notices handler that I can register for processing, works in time and as expected. So the problem can't be with DB triggers which emit notices.

The psycopg connection is in `ISOLATION_LEVEL_READ_COMMITTED` and `autocommit=False` synchronous mode.

Any suggestions to help resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry my code was buggy and execution didn't reach the part where notices get printed and popped out of the list because of exceptions. So they would have pile up and get printed after queries which didn't raise exceptions.